# Error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

When I run conda command to create tensorflow environment, it shows the following error message:

```
(Anaconda3_411) C:\development\anaconda\Anaconda3_411>conda create -n tensorflow
Error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file

You can specify one or more default packages to install when creating
an environment.  Doing so allows you to call conda create without
explicitly providing any package names.

To set the provided packages, call conda config like this:

    conda config --add create_default_packages PACKAGE_NAME
```

**Anaconda version:** Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64

**Python version:** 3.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solve the problem by providing python version in the conda command,

## >conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5

Comment: conda create -n prod python=3.7 -->>
Error: HTTPError: 404  Not Found